# Listing only some event types with CiviEvent Widget

Tags: civievent, widget

we are using the CiviEvent Widget, I’m struggling to figure out how to display a list of event ids, but not others using shortcode.
I would like for example to list events of id 9,10,11 exclusively.
I've tried seperating the id's by coma, semi-colon etc... but have had no success, it usually just displays the first id number i list.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure that is possible - but someone from AGH may know.

Answer (score 1):

The [document](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civievent-widget) says you add custom filters on shortcode

try adding

```
[civievent_widget custom_filter='{"start_date":{"IS NOT NULL":1},"id":{"IN":&#91;9,10,11&#93;},"is_public":1,"options":{"sort": "start_date ASC"}}' admin_type="custom" custom_display='{"event_title_infolink":{"title":0,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"wrapper":1},"description":{"title":1,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"wrapper":1}}' limit=5]
```

Also you will need to amend the patch below to decode html entities

```
diff --git a/civievent-widget.php b/civievent-widget.php
index e973ce0..c3c2da4 100644
--- a/civievent-widget.php
+++ b/civievent-widget.php
@@ -223,7 +223,7 @@ class civievent_Widget extends WP_Widget {
                                $standardDisplay = true;
                        } else {
                                // Get custom filters.
-                               $customFilters = json_decode( CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'custom_filter', $instance, '' ), true );
+                               $customFilters = json_decode(html_entity_decode(CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'custom_filter', $instance, '' )), true );
                                $filterParams = array(
                                        'start_date' => array( '>=' => date( 'Y-m-d' ) ),
                                        'is_public' => 1,
```

Comment: Just tried: [civievent_widget admin_type="custom" '{"id": {"IN": [9,10,11]}}' limit=10], but sadly without success

Comment: Sorry, that should have read, this is what i tried unsuccesfully: [civievent_widget admin_type="custom" custom_filter='{"id": {"IN": [9,10,11]}}' limit=10]

Comment: you need to pass custom_filter, admin_type, custom_display

Comment: Thanks for your help Ppradeep; I've tried your above suggestion. It's showing 5 events (sadly not limited to the right ID's) , and then the remaining part of the string below those 5 events: 

},”is_public”:1,”options”:{“sort”: “start_date ASC”}}’ admin_type=”custom” custom_display='{“event_title_infolink”:{“title”:0,”prefix”:null,”suffix”:null,”wrapper”:1},”description”:{“title”:1,”prefix”:null,”suffix”:null,”wrapper”:1}}’ limit=5]

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think wp short code doesn't support square bracket inside it unless there is a way

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I found that you can use `&#91;` and 93 to get around that. I've tried `[civievent_widget custom_filter='{"start_date":{"IS NOT NULL":1},"id":{"IN": &#91;9,10,11 &#93;},"is_public":1,"options":{"sort": "start_date ASC"}}' admin_type="custom" custom_display='{"event_title_infolink":{"title":0,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"wrapper":1},"description":{"title":1,"prefix":null,"suffix":null,"wrapper":1}}' limit=5]` replacing the square bracket this way means it is not displaying the string anymore. 

But it sadly still doesn't limit the displayed events to ID 9, 10 and 11.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to try and help me get this resolved. Please forgive my ignorance, but could you explain what I should do with the code you supplied above? I'm very new to this.

thanks again for the help

Comment: add the patch in your civievent-widget plugin

Comment: "add the patch in your civievent-widget plugin" how do I do this? 
Having the same issue, none of the short code examples you gave work. only need to show one event type (6)